# Optimizing matlab code which uses repmat

Tags: matlab, optimization

In some part of my code, I have used repmat for a very large vector

```
vecO=repmat(vec,1,9);
fi = repmat(vecO',1,400)-A;
```

vec is a 1 by 400 matrix and 'A' is a 3600 by 400 matrix. I think there should be a way less time-consuming than using repmat but I don't know what is the method. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your result (in your question `fi`) is supposed to contain the difference of `vec0` with each column of `A`. This means that instead of using `repmat` to expand `vec0` to the same size as `A` (by generating 400 replicates of it), you can apply an element-wise operation to two arrays with implicit expansion using [`bsxfun`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com). Using this function will not make copies of `vec0` but should achieve the same result. The first argument specifies the function to apply to the two arrays, here it is simply `minus`.

```
result = bsxfun(@minus, vec0.', A);
```

Comment: is it faster than using repmat?

Comment: I'm not sure... worth checking

Comment: I added this as a test in my "answer"

Comment: [`fi`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/fi.html) is a built-in function. So name it something else. The rest is fine

Answer (score 0):

Here is a template test to use, including [mikkola's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46540185/5358968):

```
vec = rand(1,400);
A = rand(3600,400);
n_expts = 1000;
format long
disp(version);

% Warm up
for ii = 1:n_expts
    vec0 = repmat(vec,1,9);
    res1 = repmat(vec0',1,400)-A;
    res3 = bsxfun(@minus, vec0.', A);
end

tic
for ii = 1:n_expts
    vec0 = repmat(vec, 1, 9);
    res1 = repmat(vec0.', 1, 400) - A;
end
fprintf('Time taken with 2 repmats: ')
disp(toc/n_expts)

tic
for ii = 1:n_expts
    res2 = repmat(vec.', 9, 400) - A;
end
fprintf('Time taken with 1 repmat and transpose: ')
disp(toc/n_expts)

tic
for ii = 1:n_expts
    res3 = bsxfun(@minus, vec0.', A);
end
fprintf('Time taken with bsxfun: ')
disp(toc/n_expts)

% Check that all the fi are the same
dres1 = max(max(abs(res1 - res2)));
dres2 = max(max(abs(res1 - res3)));
tol = eps;
if (dres1 > eps) | (dres2 > eps)
    fprintf('Difference in output matrices');
end
```

With results

```
8.3.0.532 (R2014a)
Time taken with 2 repmats:    0.004027661867427

Time taken with 1 repmat and transpose:    0.004034170491803

Time taken with bsxfun:    0.003970521454027
```

Comment: Thanks. Very interesting that two calls to `repmat` are faster than one call with two dimensions expand.

Comment: @Adiel Yes, that was originally going to be my suggestion. In fact, it was originally `repmat(vec, 400, 9)' - A`, but that took about 3 times as long.